# Reducing the run time transformation package

Tags: ssis

I am a new developer in business intelligence.
I have a package for transform and cleansing source data, then insert to destination table.
And I have a `dll` with .net framework for cleansing string values So I call this `dll` for every column of data type string.

So I have one `OLE DB Source`and one `Script Component`(this component is bottleneck because this is call  cleansing method per records for different columns ) and  `OLE DB Destination`
My data has 8,000,000 records.
I use `Balanced Data Distributor Component` but it doesn't reduce run time.
My system config is Ram 8Gig ,Core I3.when I execute package on this software ,that is very slow , about 2 hours .
but when I execute package on this software(Ram 12 Gig,Corei7 8then gen) ,that is very better than Weak system, about 20 minute .
I must to execute package on this config(Ram 8Gig ,Core I3);
How to I can reduce run time?
Do you have any idea?

[image: Data Flow task]

[image: Script Component For Example]

Comment: I presume the repeated cleaning of addressLine1 is to obscure sensitive column names?

Comment: this is for example, in fact it's difference column

Comment: In cases like this, you need to identify the bottleneck. Is it the source query, the script component or the destination. My guess is Script but I don't _know_ that. Does the cost/time increase linearly with the amount of columns it must clean? If you comment out all calls to the cleansing method - how long does it take. Uncomment one line - how long does that take. Double that and measure until you've hit half of the rows are uncommented. Is the time increasing with the number of elements to be cleaned?

Comment: Does the type of data being fed to the method affect timing. If the column is null, does it instantly return or does `cleansing` still do "work." Do longer values passed to cleansing impact performance? If you have 8M rows and your sample shows 21 columns, that's 168 million calls to your method (which we don't have the code) so you want to make sure that assembly is as optimized as possible.

Comment: Depending on whether this is a one time transaction volume of 8M or standard expectation of volume would then guide me on what to do. If volume was always this * I've optimized the code as best, then I'd have to rethink how I did things. Address line1 is probably fairly unique for your data set, I assume city/town will be there and that's a much smaller domain of values. It might make sense to extract the unique values, run them through a cleaner and store them back on the source system or in a  lookup table. Attempt to use reference translations and _only_ call custom script if no value found

Comment: @billinkc I have to clean all of columns and my cleansing method is optimize. this method return value if columns is null.what do I do?